# unable to make the proper design of donut chart from the victory chart

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, donut-chart, victory-charts

I want to make the donut chart from the `victory-charts`. it is working but I want to make the design like this:

[image: How I want to make the design]

I searched from many platforms but it is not working properly, the design that I made is

[image: Design that is ready]

the code that I made

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { VictoryPie, VictoryLabel } from 'victory';

function App() {
  const data = [
    { x: "Red", y: 10 },
    { x: "Green", y: 20 },
  ];
  const options = {
    colorScale: ["#3C7BBF", "#D9D9D9"],
    innerRadius: 90,
    labels: ({ datum }) => ` `
    // labels: ({ datum }) => `${datum.x}: ${datum.y}%`
  };
  const labelPosition = {
    x: 200,
    y: (400 - options.innerRadius) / 2,
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ width: '200px'}}>
      <VictoryPie style={{
        corners: {
          topLeft: 'red',
          topRight: 'red',
          bottomLeft: 'red',
          bottomRight: 'red',
        },
      }}
        data={data} {...options} width={400} height={400}
        cornerRadius={({ datum }) => datum.y * 1}
      >
      </VictoryPie>
      
      <VictoryLabel style={{ fontSize: 18  }}
          {...labelPosition}
          textAnchor="middle"
          verticalAnchor="middle"
          text="Text in the hole"
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am very disappointed because I am unable to make the same design. How to make the same design that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use circular progress bar packages instead of `victory-charts`. For example in React Native,

> import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

```
<Progress.Circle
    formatText={(progress) => `${(progress * 100).toFixed(1)}%\nUtilization`}
    textStyle={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20 }}
    showsText
    size={200}
    progress={0.554}
    thickness={25}
    strokeCap={'round'}
    color={'blue'}
    borderColor={'transparent'}
    direction={'counter-clockwise'}
    unfilledColor={'lightgrey'} 
  />
```